# phpmyadmin mysql error 1005 cant create a table

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mysql-error-1005

Recently I was looking a database on `phpmyadmin`, and I had a table called `momios_partido` which had the following columns:

```
- mopa_id int(11) **(Primary key)**
- par_id int(11) **(Foreign key references a table called "partido")**
- tiju_id int(11) **(Foreign key references a table called "tipo_jugada")**
- mopa_valor int(11) **(This one is to assign a value)**
```

Well, I was making a `select * from that table` and the `mysqld.exe` process stopped and when I restarted it, the table doesn't appear more, so I assumed that the error cleared the table, I tried create the table again and I can't create it.

I was looking for the reason, so i applied the following commands without result:

```
- flush table momios_partido
- Drop table if exists momios_partido
- Clear the .frm files in mysql/data/mydatabase:
```

[image]

And I still having the same error, so I created another table to see what happened that table I called `momiospartido` without the primary key `mopa_id` **(that means I created with `par_id, tiju_id and mopa_valor` columns)**

So the phpmyadmin allows create it, after that, I added the foreign keys to `par_id and tiju_id` and it works perfect, later when I added the field `mopa_id` and I set that field like primary key, the error appear again **(mysqld.exe has stopped and after the restart it doesn't appear more)**

So I can't create a new table with those names: `"momios_partido","momiospartido"` indistinctly of the columns that I add to the table.

The foreign keys had the same datatype (`int(11)`),the same engine INNODB and im creating it with the phpmyadmin interface without sql commands.

So what am I doing wrong?.

Hope can help me, thanks so much, greetings.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
CREATE TABLE momios_partido 
(
    mopa_id int(11) Primary key,
    par_id int(11),
    tiju_id int(11),
    mopa_valor int(11),
    FOREIGN KEY (par_id) REFERENCES partido(par_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (tiju_id) REFERENCES tipo_jugada(tiju_id)
)engine = innodb;
```

Comment: thanks for answer, i try it and appear the error again: mysqld.exe has stopped. i don't know why thats happen

Comment: Are you run it on phpMyAdmin? If it's not try it in phpMyAdmin

Comment: Right, and when i click the button "continue" the error appears

Comment: I think the problem is your mysql version or server

Comment: well  the phpmyadmin version is: 4.2.7.1 and the mysql server is: 5.5.39

Comment: Update your phpmyadmin to 4.8.4 and check that.